# Android Service Segment Fault while trying to start in Foreground

Tags: android, delphi, android-service

I'm trying to get a basic understanding of how to start the most basic android service in the foreground. I've looked at the Location Foreground sample and multiple online posts however none seems to just give a basic and straight example so that I can understand what the basics are.

To my understanding to have a service run in the foreground it has to show a constant notification so that the user knows that the service is running in the background.

I'm able to start the service successfully with the following on the StartCommand event:

```
 Result := TJService.JavaClass.START_STICKY;
// Some code that shows a notification with the NotificationCenter Component to indicate a successful start.
```

Now I'm trying to make it run in the foreground.

On the service create event I am creating the Notification Channel:

```pascal
var
  NotificationChannel := NotificationCenter.CreateChannel;
  NotificationChannel.Id := 'foreground_service';
  NotificationChannel.Title := 'Foreground test';
  NotificationChannel.Importance := TImportance.Default;

  NotificationCenter.CreateOrUpdateChannel(NotificationChannel);

 FNotificationManager := TJNotificationManager.Wrap
    (TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService
    (TJContext.JavaClass.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE));
```

The main application has 2 buttons on it. One to Start the Service and one to stop the service.

The Start Button:

```pascal
 dmService.StartForeground;
```

```pascal
procedure TdmService.StartForeground;
begin
  var
  ntf := TJNotificationCompat_Builder.JavaClass.init(TAndroidHelper.Context,
    StringToJString('foreground_service'));

  ntf.setSmallIcon(TAndroidHelper.Context.getApplicationInfo.icon);

  var
  aNtf := ntf.build;

  JavaService.StartForeground(-1, aNtf); // Causes a segment Fault
  FNotificationManager.notify(-1, aNtf);
end;
```

Why does it cause a segment fault and how can I avoid this? I also want the service to keep running even if the app is open so starting and stopping the service based on binding and unbinding it is not something I want to do.

Comment: You don't need to call `notify` for the notification created for foreground services. Do you have the Foreground Service permission checked in the Project Options?

Comment: I've added both permissions for foreground services to the host app and the service itself. Would you say my code looks correct?

Comment: You should use a logcat viewer (eg [Device Lens](https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/DeviceLens)) to determine what the underlying problem is.

Comment: I'll take a look. Out of curiosity. Does it look like my code is correct besides the `FNotificationManager.notify(-1, aNtf);`? I don't know if I'm doing it correctly or not.

Comment: It *looks* correct - I have code that [does something similar](https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/blob/3fd4c60db9b8910331b34652354fccd4d4f08488/Demos/CrossPlatformLocation/Service/CPL.ServiceModule.pas#L358)

Comment: @DaveNottage I have noticed that this only happens when changes are made to the service code.

If I make a new app and service then build and add it. It starts fine. However when I make any changes to the service and try compiling the app again thats when I get the segment fault. Am I supposed to do something after making changes to the service?